# Rails adds `AND (1=0)` to queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails somehow adds `AND (1=0)` to the SQL query of a model:

```
CompanyRelation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `company_relations`.* FROM `company_relations` WHERE `company_relations`.`vendor_id` = 1 AND (1=0)
```

Comment: You are either making use of a scope (default or otherwise), or have some strange plugin that is doing this.  Can you show the code that builds up the logic for your query?

Comment: I've added the model's code to the question.. It's dead simple.. I use Squeel, removing it doesn't fix anything..

Comment: Could it be CanCan? I use it to autoload my resources..?

Comment: You haven't posted what is triggering the query in question, not to mention how that triggering object is being built...

Comment: I guess I found it: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/733

Comment: I'm having a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886242/why-is-rails-is-adding-or-1-0-to-queries-using-the-where-clause-hash-syntax-wi/21887717) but I'm _not_ using CanCan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with CanCan:

http://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/733

Answer (score 2):

Also you can find 1=1 or 1=0 in your query if you do where(params[:data])
and data it's a hash with empty values. For example you have params hash live

```
{ village: { directions: { id: Empty Array }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the first question I found that included "rails  scope 'AND 1=0'". 
As mentioned by rossmari, there may be an empty hash. You may unintentionally be applying a scope to the conditions you use to generate a hash. This scope could leave you with an empty hash. For example

```
Assessment.last.children.for_user(user)
```

would apply the children scope inside the for_user scope which you might not be expecting. In the example below, a hash of ids is passed through the id parameter.

If you have something like

```
scope :for_user, lambda { |user|
    where(id: Question.where(assigned_to: user).... #a hash
```

then try adding unscoped

```
scope :for_user, lambda { |user|
    where(id: Question.unscoped.where(assigned_to: user).... #a hash
```

Edit: I've found that when I think I've needed unscoped, there's a good chance I've structured my queries incorrectly.